# Starting problems

Tags: toyota, starting, corolla, hot-start

My 86 Toyota Corolla starts,But when I drive it 4 plus miles and stop and try to start it again it won't until I wait 15+ minutes then it starts again whats up ?

Comment: Is it getting too hot?Have you checked the coolant level?

Comment: Adding some more details about the problem will help you get a better answer.  When you say it won't start, does it still crank?  Do you have electrical power at all?